# Any way to style LineString-features with Stroke and Fill?

Tags: openlayers

I am using the latest version of [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) to draw some features within a map rendering data from GeoJSON-files. Within each of these files I have a `FeatureCollection` containing a couple of `LineString`-features.

So far the following [style](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style-Style.html) is applied, which works fine and draws each feature as a thin dark line:

```
return new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: '#333333',
    width: 1
  })
});
```

I know, that I can not use [Fill](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Fill-Fill.html) to style `LineString`-features (if I am right). However, I really want to style these lines with two colors using a inner line (1px;red) and a border/stroke around this inner line (1px;blue).

Is there any possibility to accomplish this?

A first solution would be to copy the features drawing the lower ones blue and 3px wide and the upper ones red and 1px wide - but this would also double the amount of features.

Comment: Use two styles for the features like you wrote. Draw 3 pixel wide blue line first and 1 pixel wide red over it.You do need to copy the features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As recommanded by @user30184, you should double the style like below. You may need to adapt width to your liking.

```js
return [
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      width: 4
    })
  }),
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'red',
      width: 2
    })
  })
]
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that I could pass styles as an array.

Comment: Freakin' awesome! This helps in a lot of situations in OpenLayers styling. I haven't found anywhere in the documentation that specifically mentions this is possible.

Comment: Quite terse but explained in the API e.g in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html `style` mentioned it accepts an `module:ol/style/Style~StyleLike | null | undefined ` Then, going to `ol/style/Style~StyleLike` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style.html#~StyleLike it says it's "A Style, an array of Style, or a StyleFunction." and a `StyleFunction` should "return a module:ol/style/Style or an array of them" e.g https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style.html#~StyleFunction Clearly succinct...